# Как на github запихнуть изменение нескольких файлов в один pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Есть некий чужой репозиторий GitHub. Мне нужно добавить туда несколько файлов, но так, чтобы когда я их создам и отправлю на проверку, они составляли один pull request. Как это сделать?

**P.S.** На GitHub я новичок, поэтому просьба объяснять все предельно подробно. Если не хватает информации — скажите, я предоставлю.

Comment: Прочитать где-нибудь основы гита. В частности отправить файл в принципе нельзя. Отправить можно коммит который по определению набор файлов. Ровно то что вы хотите (наверное)

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я жму `Add file -> Create new file` , создаю его и делаю коммит. Мне нужно, чтобы при добавлении нескольких файлов это составляло один пул риквест.

Comment: надо было создать новую ветку, закоммить туда все что надо, а потом сделать пр в основную. там будут все изменения, которые внесены.

Comment: есть избыточная официальная документация, https://docs.github.com/en. в своё время мне очень помогла разобраться, что за зверь этот ваш github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пошаговая инструкция:

1. Создать форк (нажать на кнопку "Fork", вы это знаете);
2. Склонировать создавшийся репозиторий к себе на компьютер (команда `git clone <URL>` в терминале);
3. Создать ветку (`git checkout -b <ИМЯ_ВЕТКИ>` в терминале);
4. Сколько угодно коммитов;
5. Запушить на GitHub все эти коммиты;
6. Уже в веб-интерфейсе, создаём пулл-реквест.
7. Ждём, пока вольют :)

Comment: А без терминала никак? А то у меня git не устанавливается. Да и работать с этой библиотекой я не умею.

Comment: @Глеб - а как вы гит устанавливаете?

Comment: @ESkri, `pip install git`, а надо как-то по другому? Или его вообще не надо устанавливать?

Comment: git устанавливается запуском инсталлятора гита.  под винду он называется git-for-windows.  не в питоне.

Comment: @ESkri, понял, спасибо за разъяснение.